# Dutch Higher education degrees have a major or a minor?

Tags: netherlands

The Dutch education system adds a major or minor to their Higher professional education or University education? I saw some examples as: HBO Management (would HBO be the degree and Management the major, or HBO Management is the degree). I am doing a comparison with the US education system.

Comment: MBO is vocational education, so that is not an appropriate question for this forum. Maybe your question can be saved when you tell us why you want to know that

Comment: I am not sure why this is put on hold, as the question pertains to how higher education (in a particular country) is organized. (Note that  HBO institutions are essentially non-research universities that only confer undergraduate degrees, somewhat like US teaching colleges.)

Comment: I thought the same thing @mmeent, I do believe my question is valid. So respecting to your comment about HBO institutions, in the US the bachelor and the major go together in the degree title, i.e. BBA in Finance, BBA is the Bachelors in Business Administration, Finance the major or subject of study. Dutch students/individuals would add the HBO and the major or subject of study as their Degree title? Or only the HBO is mentioned (diploma only).

Answer (score 4):

(As mentioned in the comments) It is possible to do a minor while at university in the Netherlands - for example, on the [Biology course of Radboud University](https://www.ru.nl/english/education/bachelors/biology/curriculum-and-courses/minors/), it is possible to do 15-30 ECTS on a minor subject.

[This website](https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/education-in-the-netherlands/#higher-education) gives more information about higher education in the Netherlands, but you can confirm for yourself by looking at the course descriptions at other universities.

Comment: The Netherlands do in fact have a minor in the bachelor, usually consisting of 30 ECTS.

Comment: Thanks, @BrtH! I'll edit the answer to include that, if you don't mind.

Comment: @BrtH so if I understood this correctly, to have a minor would depend on the course program but what about the major? (as we called major to the subject of study in the US). A CV would have the HBO and the major or subject of study? In the US we add the bachelor and the major, i.e. BBA in Finance, BBA is the Bachelors in Business Administration, Finance the major or subject of study.